# Bigquery Delete Query with Union All & Wildcards

Tags: google-bigquery

Would like to delete data from multiple tables in bigquery.

Below delete syntax is working to delete single table without Union all or wildcard

```
delete  FROM `abc.analytics_151541058.events_20190201` WHERE event_date='20190201'
```

Below delete query with Union all did not worked

```
delete  FROM `abc.analytics_151541058.events_20190201` WHERE event_date='20190201'
UNION ALL 
delete  FROM `abc.analytics_151541058.events_20190201` WHERE event_date='20190202'
```

Below delete query with wildcard did not worked

```
delete  FROM `abc.analytics_151541058.events_*`,  
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190202'
```

Pls. Help

Comment: BigQuery doesn't support DML over wildcard tables.

Comment: Is there any have to delete multiple tables in bigquery. Pls. Help

Comment: Only if you setup a piece of code to do it.

Comment: can you pls. help me on how to achieve this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) is in Beta now.

You can now simply stack multiple DELETE statements like:

```
delete  FROM `abc.analytics_151541058.events_20190201` WHERE event_date='20190201'
delete  FROM `abc.analytics_151541058.events_20190202` WHERE event_date='20190202'
```